# The function "pytesseract.image_to_string" returns strings without convenient separation parameters

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to scan images in strings using tesseract to manipulate these strings for creating a script to autofill excel cells.

I just imported all the libraries needed 'cause i'm using colab:

```
!sudo apt install tesseract-ocr

!pip install pytesseract

import pytesseract
import shutil
import os
import random
import pandas as pd
import io
try:
 from PIL import Image
except ImportError:
 import Image

from google.colab import drive #acessesando os arquivos no drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

directory = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/S N'
for filename in os.listdir (directory): #os.listdir() method in python is used to get the list of all files and directories in the specified directory..
  f = os.path.join(directory,filename) #"path.join()" join one or more path components intelligently
  imagestring = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(f)) #object with recognizable strings by tesseract function.
  print(imagestring)
```

in theory all images were read correctly:

```
N/S:10229876-5

192.1638.1 729.200

192.168.179.103 SPARE
```

The problem begins when one of these strings tesseract has returned has a blank space within(192.1638.1**X**729.200) and the "str.split()" don't work because of it.

I just need to separate those string to structure a dataframe which will allow me to continue with my goal.

Comment: This is not a portuguese site.

Comment: Sorry, forgot about it! just translated it all. And thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**I just found out a way to separate those strings individually by using de re module.
i just called**

```
import re
string_lists = re.split('',imagestring,1)

print(string_lists)
```

**And result was**:

['', 'N/S:10229876-5\n\x0c']

['', '192.1638.1 729.200\n\x0c']

['', '192.168.179.103 SPARE\n\x0c']

Now i just need to strip out the '' and \n\x0c'. And after that append all these lists in one list.